# How to running ServerAgent on Windows?

Tags: jmeter, windows

Running the startAgent.bat command for ServerAgent on Windows resulted in an error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've [cloned the server agent repository](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/tree/master) which doesn't contain any binaries, only the source code.

You should rather [download installation package](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/releases/download/2.2.3/ServerAgent-2.2.3.zip) and unpack it into your preferred location, this way you will be able to start the server agent process by running `startAgent.bat` script.

If you want to build it from sources you can execute [`maven package`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#packaging) command and it will produce `ServerAgent-x.x.x.zip` file under "target" folder which you will be able to unpack where required and run the `startAgent.bat` script from there

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)